# Boundary Condition for Convertible Bond under Two-factor Model Interest Rate

Tags: options, interest-rates, bond

I want to find Boundary conditions for Convertible Bond under  Two-factor Model Interest Rate.The portfolio contains stock where stochastic differential equation for the stock price is 
\begin{align}
ds_t=rS_t+\sigma S_tdW_1(t)
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ is constant and dynamics of $r$ as follow
\begin{align}
dr_t=\kappa(\theta-r_t)dt+\Sigma dW_2(t)
\end{align}

Comment: Boundary conditions was defined on PDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a two-factor option pricing model with underlying variables $S$ and $r$ defined as above, if we assume there is **no correlation between** the two Wiener
processes $W_1$ and $W_2$, one finds the **generalized Black-Scholes PDE**
\begin{align}
V_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2V_{SS}+r\,S\,V_S-r\,V+\frac{1}{2}\Sigma\,^2\,V_{rr}+\kappa(\theta-r)V_r=0
\end{align}
This equation is subject to initial and boundary conditions. Generally speaking, derivative pricing models for different financial scenarios may share a similar pricing partial differential equation (PDE) with adjusted parameters
and boundary conditions.Boundary conditions defining two portfolios will be considered. The first set of conditions will describe a European call stock option. The second set of conditions models a convertible bond. The stock price $S$ and interest rate, $r$.

1. At the maturity time T, the call option price will be the payoff function
   \begin{align}
   V(S,r,T)=\max\{S-K,0\}
   \end{align}
2. At $S = 0$, the option is worthless:
   \begin{align}
   V(0,r,T)=0
   \end{align}
3. For large stock price $S_{\max}$, it is almost certain that the bond will be
   converted to one share of the stock. Hence
   \begin{align}
   V(S_{\max},r,t)=S_{\max}
   \end{align}
4. When $r_t$ is infinitely large, the bond component tends to zero. Since we
   do not enforce any time-dependent constraints of puttable and callable features, the upper bound and the lower bound to the price of the convertible
   bond are $\max\{S,\infty\}$ and $\max\{S,0\}$ respectively. Therefore we define the boundary condition as
   \begin{align}
   V(S,r_{\max},t)=\min\left\{\max\{S,\infty\},\max\{S,0\}\right\}=S
   \end{align}
5. For a very small interest rate, we use homogeneous Neumann condition suggested by [Bermudez and Nogueiras](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218202504003246).