# Ito lemma of Convertible Bond under Two-factor Model Interest Rate

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, hedging, convertible-bond

@Behrouz Maleki has provided the PDE of two factor model in [other post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/boundary-condition-for-convertible-bond-under-two-factor-model-interest-rate) so 
could anyone please provide Ito lemma of this equation and how this PDE was derived from Vasicek model. as far as I know it is by constructing a portfolio. right?

Answer (score 6):

Let $V(t, r_t, S_t)$ be the convertible bond price at time $t$, where
\begin{align*}
dS_t &= S_t(r_t dt + \sigma dW_t^1)\\
dr_t &=\kappa(\theta-r_t)dt+\Sigma dW_t^2,
\end{align*}
and where $\{W_t^1, \, t\ge 0\}$ and $\{W_t^2, \, t\ge 0\}$ are two standard Brownian motions with $d\langle W^1, W^2\rangle_t = \rho dt$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
&\ dV(t, r_t, S_t) \\
=&\ \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}dr_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}dS_t \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2}d\langle r, r\rangle_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}d\langle S, S\rangle_t +\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial r}d\langle S, r\rangle_t\\
=&\ \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \kappa(\theta-r_t) \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + r_tS_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + \rho\sigma\Sigma\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial r}\right)dt \\
&\ +\Sigma \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}dW_t^2 + \sigma S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}dW_t^1.
\end{align*}
We note that, under the risk-neutral measure, $\{e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds} V_t, \, t \ge 0\}$ is a martingale. By Ito's lemma,
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds} V_t \right) &= -r_t e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds} V_t dt + e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds} dV_t\\
&= e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\bigg[\bigg(-r_t V_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \kappa(\theta-r_t) \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + r_tS_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + \rho\sigma\Sigma\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial r}\bigg)dt\\
&\quad + \Sigma \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}dW_t^2 + \sigma S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}dW_t^1\bigg].
\end{align*}
By the martingality property,
\begin{align*}
& -r_t V_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \kappa(\theta-r_t) \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + r_tS_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \\
&\qquad + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + \rho\sigma\Sigma\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial r}=0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
This is the PDE satisfied by the instrument price. If Brownian motions $\{W_t^1, \, t\ge 0\}$ and $\{W_t^2, \, t\ge 0\}$ are independent, that is, $\rho=0$, then Equation $(1)$ becomes
\begin{align*}
-r_t V_t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \kappa(\theta-r_t) \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + r_tS_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} =0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Many thanks Gordon .. I need reference please?

Comment: I do not have a specific reference, but most of the mathematical finance book should be fine. Which part is not clear to you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. How did you get (1) in details? how did you drop dt and stochastic dw?

Comment: A martingale has a zero drift, that is, the coefficient of then $dt$ term is zero, which leads to our PDE.

Answer (score 3):

Gordon's Answer is nice (+1). I want to add the other solution.

**Remark 1**

Let $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ where the component $X_i$ has a stochastic differential of the form
$$dX_i(t)=\mu_i(t)dt+\sum_{j=1}^{d}\sigma_{ij}(t)dW_j(t)$$
where $dW_k(t)dW_j(t)=\rho_{kj}dt$, for all $k,j\in\{1,2,...,d\}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\in\mathbb{C}^{1,2}.$ By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$df(t,X_1,...,X_n)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dX_i+\frac 12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_l}dX_idX_l\tag 1$$

---

**Remark 2**

Assume that the short rate $r_t$ follows the Ito process as described by the following stochastic differential equation
$$dr_t=\mu(t,r_t)dt+\sigma(t,r_t)dW_t$$
and $P(t,T)$ denotes the zero-coupon bond price with maturity $T$. We can show 
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\mu(t,r_t)\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,r_t)\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial r^2}-r_tP=0\tag 2$$

---

**Remark 3**

Let
$$\qquad dS_t=rS_t+\sigma S_tdW_1(t)\\
\quad\qquad\quad dr_t=\kappa(\theta-r_t)dt+\Sigma dW_2(t)\\
dW_1(t)dW_2(t)=0\tag 3$$

Now we form a portfolio consisting of one option $V=V(t,S,r,T,K)$ (Short position), $\Delta_1$ units of the stock (long position) and $\Delta_2$ units of the $T-$zero-coupon bond price (long position). The portfolio has value
$$\Pi=\Delta_1S_t+\Delta_2 P(t,T)-V(t,S,r,T,K)$$
therefore
$$d\Pi=\Delta_1dS_t+\Delta_2dP(t,T)-dV(t,S,r,T,K)\tag 4$$
By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$dV_t=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}dS+\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}dr+\frac 12\left(\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial s^2}+\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2}\right)dt\tag 5$$
and
$$dP=\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}dr+\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial r^2}dt\tag 6$$
$(4)\,,\,(5)\,,(6)$ and $(3)$
$$d\Pi =-\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}{{S}^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{S}^{2}}} \right)dt+\left( \Delta _1-\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right)dS\\+\left( \Delta _2\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}\,-\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \right)dr+\Delta _2\,\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\Sigma }^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}P}{\partial {{r}^{2}}} \right)dt\,$$
We then find the values of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ that makes the portfolio riskless. Indeed, we set
$$ \Delta_1=\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\\
\Delta_2=\frac{\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}}$$
thus
$$d\Pi =-\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}{{S}_{t}}^{2}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{S}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2}{{\Sigma }^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{r}^{2}}} \right)dt+\Delta {{}_{2}}\,\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\Sigma }^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}P}{\partial {{r}^{2}}} \right)dt\tag 7$$
$(2)$ and $(7)$
$$d\Pi =-\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}{{S}^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{S}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2}{{\Sigma }^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{r}^{2}}} \right)dt+\Delta {{}_{2}}\,\left( {{r}_{t}}\,P-\kappa \left( \theta -r \right)\,\frac{\partial P}{\partial r} \right)dt\tag 8$$
The condition that the portfolio earn the risk-free rate, $r$, implies that the change in portfolio value is $$d\Pi=r\Pi dt$$
in other words
$$d\Pi =(\Delta _1r_t\,S_t+\Delta_2r_tP-r_tV)dt\tag 9$$
$(8)$ and $(9)$
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+{{r}_{t}}\,{{S}_{t}}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+\kappa \left( \theta -r \right)\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\sigma }^{2}}{{S}^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{S}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2}{{\Sigma }^{2}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}V}{\partial {{r}^{2}}}-{{r}_{t}}V=0$$

Comment: A good alternative addition.

Comment: You are really incredible guys .. Many thanks

Comment: can I have a reference for that please?

Comment: using this PDE, can we get the exact or closed solution of convertible bond with Vasicek?

Comment: We sell one option and buy $\Delta _1$ unit Stock and $\Delta_2$ unit Zero-coupon bond

Comment: Also , $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\mu(t,r_t)\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,r_t)\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial r^2}-r_tP=0 $$ then $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,r_t)\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial r^2}=r_tP-\mu(t,r_t)\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}$$ Note $$\mu(t,r_t)=\kappa(\theta-r_t)$$

Comment: I got it ..Many thanks ... still wondering if there is an exact solution for V?

Comment: Yes , there is it , just we can use the numerical solution when we have PDE

Comment: Dear Maleki .. I need to find duration and convexity and as you know i have to differentiate V twice.. but wondering what is V? i know that convertible bond= bond+option+premium