# Finding a PDE for an option $V(t,r(t),S(t))$

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, portfolio, replication, differential-equations

I have 2 approaches in my mind for finding a pde of an option that depends both on the short rate as well as the stock price- $V(t,r(t),S(t)$. Are these equivalent?

1. Find a hedging portfolio by shorting delta of the stock and delta ratio of the option to a ZCB. So my portfolio has the underlying stock, a ZCB, and the money market. What is left must be riskless and I get a PDE. The ZCB has its own PDE (say Hull White) which I can use that to manipulate and obtain the final PDE without having a ZCB price in it.
2. Use Ito's Lemma and write that $exp(-∫r(u)du) V(t,r(t),S(t))$ is a martingale (where limits of the integral are from 0 to t.) and thus put its drift equal to 0.

Comment: Have a look of [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30956/ito-lemma-of-convertible-bond-under-two-factor-model-interest-rate/30962#30962).

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you!